Can one show $h(x)=|2(\zeta'(x))^2-\zeta''(x)\zeta(x)|$ is a decreasing function for $x\in\mathbb{R}\cap [1,\infty)$?
This question is related to This question.
When I tried to approach it I couldn't even proof that the LHS is a decreasing function on the given domain using regular methods. I have tried to write the dirichlet series and got some messy coefficients. I calculated Their values upto $1000$ and it seems the are not all positive.

$\newcommand\z\zeta\newcommand{\ga}{\gamma}\newcommand{\de}{\delta}$Yes, $h$ is a decreasing function (on $(1,\infty)$).
Indeed, let
\begin{equation}
    g:=2{\z'}^2-\z''\z, 
\end{equation}
so that $h=|g|$. It is easy to see that $g(\infty-)=0$. So, it is enough to show that $g$ is increasing.
Note that
\begin{equation}
    g'=3\z'\z''-\z\z'''. 
\end{equation}
We have the Laurent series expansion
\begin{equation}
    \z(x)=\frac1{x-1}+\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\,\ga_n(x-1)^n
\end{equation}
for $x$ in a neighborhood of $1$, where the $\ga_n$'s are the Stieltjes constants, with the bounds
\begin{equation}
    |\ga_n|\le\frac{4(n-1)!}{\pi^n}
\end{equation}
for $n\ge1$ and $\ga_0=\ga$, the Euler constant.
So, for $k\ge1$ and $x\in(1,1+\pi)$,
\begin{equation}
    \Big|\z^{(k)}(x)-\frac{(-1)^k k!}{(x-1)^{k+1}}\Big|
    \le r_k(x):=\sum_{n\ge k}\frac{4(n-1)!}{\pi^n}\frac{(x-1)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}
    =\frac{4\pi(k-1)!}{(\pi+1-x)^k}.  
\end{equation}
Also, for $x\in(1,1+\pi)$,
\begin{equation}
    \z(x)\ge\frac1{x-1}+\ga-\tilde r_0(x), 
\end{equation}
where $\tilde r_0(x):=4\ln\frac\pi{\pi+1-x}$. So,
\begin{equation}
    g'(x)\ge\Big(\frac1{x-1}+\ga-\tilde r_0(x)\Big)
    \Big(\frac6{(x-1)^4}-r_3(x)\Big) \\ 
    -\Big(\frac1{(x-1)^2}+r_1(x)\Big)\Big(\frac2{(x-1)^3}+r_2(x)\Big)>0 
\tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation}
for
\begin{equation}
    x\in\Big(1,\frac{119}{100}\Big].
\end{equation}
Next, for $k\ge1$,
\begin{equation}
    \z^{(k)}(x)=\sum_{n\ge2}\frac{\ln^k n}{n^x}. 
\end{equation}
Note that $\frac{\ln n}{n^x}$ and $\frac{\ln^2 n}{n^x}$ are convex in $n\ge5/2$ for each real $x\ge7/2$. So,
\begin{equation}
    |\z'(x)|\le\frac{\ln2}{2^x}+I_1(x),\quad 
    |\z''(x)|\le\frac{\ln^2 2}{2^x}+I_2(x),
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
    I_1(x):=\int_{5/2}^\infty dn\,\frac{\ln n}{n^x}
    <\frac{132}{100}\,\frac1{(5/2)^x},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    I_2(x):=\int_{5/2}^\infty dn\,\frac{\ln^2 n}{n^x}
    <\frac{19}{10}\,\frac1{(5/2)^x}.
\end{equation}
Also, $\z\ge1$ and $-\z'''\ge\frac{\ln^3 2}{2^x}$
for $x>1$. So,
\begin{equation}
    g'(x)\ge\frac{\ln^3 2}{2^x}
    -\Big(\frac{\ln2}{2^x}+\frac{132}{100}\,\frac1{(5/2)^x}\Big)
    \Big(\frac{\ln^2 2}{2^x}+\frac{19}{10}\,\frac1{(5/2)^x}\Big) >0
\end{equation}
for $x\ge7/2$.
It remains to show that $g'>0$ on the interval $(\frac{119}{100},\frac72]=(\frac{119}{100},\frac{350}{100}]$.
This can be done by the interval method. Indeed, note that
\begin{equation}
    g''=3{\z''}^2+2\z' \z'''-\z \z''''>b:=-\z \z''''. 
\end{equation}
Therefore and because $b$ is decreasing,
\begin{equation}
    g''(x)\ge b(x_*) \text{ if } x\ge x_*>1. 
\end{equation}
So, on any nonempty interval $(a,a+\de]\in(1,\infty)$ we have $g'\ge g'(a)+b(a)\de$.
Using the latter fact for intervals

$(\frac{119}{100}+\frac{j-1}{250},\frac{119}{100}+\frac{j}{250}]$ with $j=1,\dots,(\frac{127}{100}-\frac{119}{100})/\frac1{250}$

$(\frac{127}{100}+\frac{j-1}{100},\frac{127}{100}+\frac{j}{100}]$ with $j=1,\dots,(\frac{190}{100}-\frac{127}{100})/\frac1{100}$

$(\frac{190}{100}+\frac{j-1}{10},\frac{190}{100}+\frac{j}{10}]$ with $j=1,\dots,(\frac{350}{100}-\frac{190}{100})/\frac1{10}$


we complete the proof. $\quad\Box$
(To verify that $g'>0$ on each of these many intervals of the form $(a,a+\de]\in(1,\infty)$, we just have to check that for each such interval we have $g'(a)+b(a)\de>0$ and recall that $g'\ge g'(a)+b(a)\de$ on $(a,a+\de]$. )

Thank you for your time and effort! I will study your proof.

Can you see if you are able to proof the inequality I mentioned in the question?

@Haidara : I think that inequality, too, can be proved similarly (if it is true).

Can you please explain the last step in your proof since I don't know what is the interval method?

@Haidara : There is actually almost nothing to know about the interval method. Anyhow, I have now added a paragraph at the end of the answer with the corresponding detail.

@Haidara : Now there also is a proof of your other conjecture.

@IosifPinelis: Cany you kindly explann the latest inequality "$g'\ge g'(a)+b(a)\delta$ on $(a,a+\delta]$", giving us details?

@user64494 : As noted in the answer, this follows because $g''(x)\ge b(x_)$ if $x\ge x_>1$.

@IosifPinelis: Sorry, you avoid of answer. Also $g'$ without  amy argument looks  strange, saying in mild words.

@user64494 : $g'$ without an argument is the function; $g'(t)$ is the value of the function $g'$ at $t$. To get $g'\ge g'(a)+b(a)\delta$ on $(a,a+\delta]$, take any $t\in(a,a+\delta]$ and write $g'(t)=g'(a)+\int_a^t ds, g''(s)\ge g'(a)+\int_a^t ds, b(a)=g'(a)+b(a)(t-a)\le g'(a)+b(a)\delta$.

@IosifPinelis:  Thank you so much Unfortunately, $b(a)$ is not described.

@user64494 : $b$ was defined as $-\zeta\zeta''''$.

In my previous comment, read of course $\ge g'(a)+b(a)\delta$ instead of $\le g'(a)+b(a)\delta$.

@IosifPinelis: You wrote ":$b$ was defined as $-\zeta\zeta''''$. What is the argument of the RHS?

@user64494 : I did not use there any arguments. Rather, there I used standard mathematical definitions of pointwise operations over functions, according to which the function $-fg$ would be defined by the condition that $(-fg)(x):=-f(x)g(x)$ for any (say) real-valued functions $f$ and $g$ defined on a set $X$ and all $x\in X$.  Also, when referring to a function $h$, one must not confuse it with one of its values $h(t)$. Frankly, I find it strange that I have to answer such questions on MathOverflow.

@IosifPinelis: Sorry, I have never seen such "standard mathematical definitions". I repeat the question : You wrote '$b$  was defined as $-\zeta\zeta''''$" .What is the argument of the RHS?".

@user64494 : I already said that there I used no arguments. I am sorry to hear that you had never seen things like the definition of the product $fg$ of functions $f$ and $g$. Are you familiar with such basic things as the Stone–Weierstrass theorem, where the symbol $fg$ is used -- of course without any arguments?

Previous comment continued: Or with vector spaces of functions, where sums $f+g$ of functions $f$ and $g$ are used -- again without any arguments? In any case, in my previous comment I gave the definition of the function $-fg$. So, the definition $b:=-\zeta\zeta''''$ should now make sense to you. I am afraid I cannot be of further help to you.

@IosifPinelis: Sorry, I draw the conclusion thay you avoid of the answer to my request.  That's all.
